# splitting larger array in to smaller array

Tags: android

In my app I have array size 400 elements. My task is Those elements are send to webservice for inserting.But it is not supported.So split the array into pieces and send to webservice.How is it

Comment: Post some code. I don't see why you would have to split the array.

Comment: Just use Arrays.copyOfRange function inside a loop.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this, perhaps?

```
   String[] stringArray = new String[400];    
    //lets assume that the array has objects in it.   
    int index = 0;   
    for(int i = 0; i < stringArray.length; i++) {   
        String[] temp = new String[20];   
        for(int x = 0; x < 20) {   
            if(stringArray[index] != null)  temp[x] = stringArray[index];   
            index++;   
        }   
        //The temp array is filled with objects from the other array, so send it to the webservice. 
        sendArrayToWebService(temp);   
    }
```